# How to use vertical headings in Excel tables

Tags: excel

I am currently using Excel 2013. I wanted to use vertical headings in tables instead of horizontal ones. Horizontal headers take a lot of space but vertical ones don't.

I looked upon a number of web sites but not even one gave an intelligent answer. There were answers like inserting a section break or an image, etc.

I am a 9th grade student.

Comment: What's a vertical heading? Is that text displayed vertically, or are you just wanting to merge the cells of a column that spans many rows?

Comment: I want the headers to go row-wise instead of column-wise

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text direction by editting the "Format" of a cell or range of cells:

**A table:**

[image]

**Right click on the header cells after selecting them and go to "Format Cells":**

[image]

**Go to the Alignment tab and change the alignment to 90 degrees:**

[image]

**Click OK and your text will be vertically aligned.** You can align the cell text to the left using the button at the top to make it a bit prettier if you want:

[image]

Good luck on the class!

Comment: Sir, you did not understand me. I mean in your example the headers are going from the column A to E. I want to them to go from the row 1 to 8. But I respect your answer

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but it wasn't clear. The answer is a bit easier then. Copy the table by highlighting and `Ctrl+C` or Right-Click "Copy" and then in an empty area: Right-Click "Paste Special" and choose "Transpose". It will transpose rows to columns, and bob's your uncle. Note that it won't be a formal "Table" any longer though if you are using Excel's "Table" feature (sometimes also called a "List").

Comment: Yes, that is what I do not want. It should still be a formal "Table"

Comment: I'm not 100% positive on this one, but I'm pretty certain that there is no support for that in Excel. : (